# How to arrange the value of active account?

Tags: laravel

The idea is that I need to show the status of user account whether `Active` or `Inactive`
in blade file, so in database there column active his default is `null`, when in blade I need to do this if to show the status of user:

```
<td>{{ $user->active ? "active" : 'Inactive' }}</td>
```

So I search A little bit and found this way to short above code:

```
public function getActiveBladeAttribute($a)
{
    return [
        null =>'Inactive',
        1 =>'Active',
    ][$a];

}
```

and when refresh my page it is not works :(
and show this error

> Undefined index

It is highlit the (  null =>'Inactive' ) in error.

So what is the best way to make short cut for these cases ?

Comment: what is the value of `$a` ?

Comment: @lagbox without any value :|  just {{ $user->ActiveBlade }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getActiveBladeAttribute()` is on your `User` model, you can simply use `$this` to access the variables of the current user:

```
public function getActiveBladeAttribute(){
    return $this->active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
}
```

And, in your view, simply call:

```
{{ $user->activeBlade }}
```

Generally, in `get{Param}Attribute()` functions, you don't need to pass anything, as `$this` is available.

Comment: It happens :) I think you were just overthinking it; that array syntax, while a neat idea, is pretty unnecessary when you only have 2 options for `active` (technically 3, `null`, `0` and `1` maybe?)

Comment: No mate, it just two value :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do the same thing you are doing in the view:

```
public function getActiveBladeAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['active'] ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
}
```

If you want to be tricky with the array you could do it that way as well:

```
return ['Inactive', 'Active'][(bool) $this->active];
// or with (int) cast instead of (bool)
```

Comment: is there any other way to just make one like that {{ $user->ActiveBlade }} and in back check if he active or not, without ant if in blade ?

Comment: this isn't in blade .. this is in the accessor